# ElasticSearch Delete Query - Filter with term and range

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query that I am trying to use to delete data from an [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) index.

```
{
    "filter": {
        "and": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "Time": {
                        "from": "20120101T000000",
                        "to": "20120331T000000"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "term": {
                    "Source": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried to delete documents based on this query. This query returns results fine when I run it against the index. But when I try to run a delete command against the index, nothing happens.

I am not sure if I am constructiing the query wrong or what else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using only a filter while the [delete by query API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/delete-by-query.html) probably needs a query. You can convert your filter to a query using a [filtered query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/filtered-query.html) like this:

```
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter": {
            "and": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "Time": {
                            "from": "20120101T000000",
                            "to": "20120331T000000"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "Source": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise you could convert your filter to a query using a [bool query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query.html) with two must clauses, so that you don't need a filtered query anymore. Anyway, I guess the filter approach is better since filters are faster.

Comment: Note that you don't actually need the `query` component inside filtered: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html#_filtering_without_a_query

Comment: link provided to elasticsearch.com is no longer a valid link